# Probability of an "anti-run" in a sequence of draws of RV?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've been pondering the following problem (I thought up) for a couple of days and have made no progress.

Imagine an N-sided die with probability of the faces $p_1, p_2, ..., p_n$.

You roll the die $M$ times and note the face value for each roll of the sequence.

What is the probability that there is a contiguous segment of length $L$ or greater, $N <= L <= M$, within the sequence of rolls that does not have at least one instance of each of the $N$ faces?

Comment: a contiguous segment???? what is that???? It is like 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1?

Answer (score 0):

A contiguous segment of length $k$ and value $i$ located at $x=1...M-k+1$ has probability:
$$
S_{ikx}=p_i^k
$$

Having no segment in the contiguous sides happens with probability $1-p_i$ if is in a border and $(1-p_i)^2$ if is in between. Others values are not important supposing $k>M/2$ i.e. supposing the segments are enough large to happens just once in a trial.

Hence the segments happens with probability, for each faces and locations:
$$
S_{k}=(M-k-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)^2 p_i^k+2\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)p_i^k
$$
And for each lengths, including those pathological cases when the segments cover everything:
$$
S=\sum_{k=L}^{M-1}\left((M-k-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)^2 p_i^k+2\sum_{i=1}^n (1-p_i)p_i^k\right)\\
+\sum_{i=1}^n p_i^{M}
$$

If the length $k$ is enough small for allowing more than one contiguous segments per trial, hence including the factor of additional lengths, extracting the case of them being equal and contiguous, which would actually be a longer sequence. Of course, this is left as exercise to the OP.
$$
\lfloor M/k \rfloor
$$